# What is difference between Angular app-routing.module.ts and app.routes.ts

Tags: angular

I need to know the difference between Angular app-routing.module.ts and app.routes.ts
and any best practices. I am using Angular latest. 17.0.10.

Comment: *app.routes.ts* is the file in which you declare/define the routes. *app-routing.module.ts* is the file where you declare the class with `NgModule` decorator by importing the routes into the `RouterModule` and exporting the `RouterModule`. Next you import the AppRoutingModule to your root module of Angular app.

Comment: Note that as you use Angular 17 and work with standalone components, `AppRoutingModule` is not required as you can register the routes with [`provideRouter`](https://angular.io/api/router/provideRouter).

Answer (score 0):

Routing module requires a list of routes in its' configuration. We could just inline this potentially very long list of routes in same file, or we could move list of routes to `const routes` in separate file, to not have a long list in the middle of file with routing and other logic. Moving routes to separate file makes reading file with routing logic easier